# What's the gender of digits and numbers?

Tags: gender

> **This question also has an answer here (in German):**
>   *[Was für ein Geschlecht hat eine Zahl?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/47690/9551)*

In my textbook I noticed that one of the characters uses feminine gender when pointing at a number written somewhere, precisely what he says is "Das ist eine 8". I know from Google etc. that letters are strictly neutral (as in "Das ist ein B"), but I've not found any clue on how to distinguish genders for a digit. In Russian, though, we associate almost every number with feminine, the only exceptions are zero and numbers of big magnitude like 1 million, 1 billion etc., which are masculine.

So for German, do you also have most of them as feminine so I can follow my "Russian intuition" for them, or are there drastically different rules, or even maybe every speaker decides themselves?

Comment: https://youtu.be/Y60LlHchdEI

Answer (score 9, accepted):

German has two sets of number words. One set is the one that you heard in your textbook, which grammatically is just the direct nominalisation of the cardinal numbers. These are all *feminine* (no exception).

> Die 357 folgt auf die 356.
>   Ich nehme die Elf (Buslinie) nach Hause.
>   Bei der Vierzehn (Eintrag) ist die Adresse falsch.
>   Die Dreiundachtzig (Rückennummer) spielt heute aber schlecht.
>   Du musst eine Sechs würfeln.

The second set of numbers is a derivative nominalisation using the suffix *-er*. This suffix is grammatically masculine and therefore so is this set of numbers (again, no exception). These are often uncommon for very large numbers but do exist — most often in the case of round numbers.

> Ich nehme den Elfer (Buslinie) nach Hause.
>   Beim Vierzehner (Eintrag) ist die Adresse falsch.
>   Der Dreiundachtziger (Rückennummer) spielt heute aber schlecht.
>   Du musst einen Sechser würfeln.
>   Das bezahle ich mit einem Hunderttausender (Geldschein).

As you can maybe already tell from my choice of examples, these two sets of numbers are similar but distinct. Generally, the feminine version is preferred across most parts of Germany when the topic is the actual number, while the masculine one is preferred when the number represents something (especially in the example of the banknote).

In which case which is preferred is not always clear. For example, in Braunschweig, bus lines are generally referred to by the feminine version while in Munich the masculine version would be preferred.

Comment: Die Beispiele im ersten Block mit der Buslinie und der Rückennummer halte ich nicht für aussagekräftig, da sich hier das Geschlecht aus dem jeweils in Klammern stehenden Wort ergibt. Spräche man beispielsweise von den Metrolinien A, B und C, würde man "Ich nehme die [Linie] A und du die C." sagen, obwohl der *Buchstabe* C "das C" hieße.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Guter Punkt!

Comment: Zu einer Fünf kann man aber auch "ein Fünfer" sagen, und der ist maskulin.

Comment: @glglgl Lies die zweite Hälfte der Antwort ;)

Comment: @Jan Stimmt, steht ja schon da.

Answer (score 5):

The rules are quite simple actually: all numbers in German are feminine. It's easy to remember because *die Zahl* is also feminine.

This does include zero and numbers of big magnitude. Die Null, die Million, die Milliarde, etc. are all feminine as well.

Exception Austria: There could be regional variations though. In the south, it is often masculine instead (from Einser, Zweier etc.)

Comment: Can you provide any evidence for your claim of masculine numbers on the south? Never heard that.

Comment: *Das ist ein Einser, ein Zweier, ein Dreier, ... , ein Achter, ein Neuner*. Valid in my region (south-west)

Comment: Yes, I should have made that clear. My apologies.

Comment: »all numbers in German are feminine« is simply wrong. And to say »because die Zahl is also feminine« would even be nonsense, if all numbers really was feminine.

Comment: Well except for the southern variants it isn't wrong, and I didn't say it was derived from Zahl being feminine, just that it was easy to remember because they matched.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast The Standard German words (Null, Eins, Zwei, Drei, ...  ) for digits and numbers are female... Obviously we can talk about all dialects and variants here but what's the point?

Comment: @adjan: Die Zahlwörter eins, zwei, drei usw. sind keine Substantive und werden daher auch kleingeschrieben. Nur Substantive haben ein Geschlecht, also muss man die Zahlwörter erst mal substantivieren. Diese Substantivierung der Zahlwörter verläuft im deutschen Deutsch nach einem anderem Muster als im österreichischen Deutsch. In einem Fall ist das Ergebnis »die Eins, die Zwei, die Drei«, im anderen »der Einser, der Zweier, der Dreier«. Beide Varietäten sind Standarddeutsch, und beide sind qualitativ gleichwertig. Keine von beiden ist ein Dialekt. Deutsches Deutsch hat lediglich mehr Sprecher.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Ich meine ja auch die Substantive. Nicht die Kardinalzahlen. Schau doch einfach in den Duden. Dort sind alle substantivierten Zahlwörter die großgeschriebenen Kardinalwörter. Guckt man bei z.B. "der Dreier" nach, stehen dort  neben den weiteren Bedeutungen von "Dreier" nur dass es die "landschaftliche" Varietät von "die Drei" ist. Wie gesagt, es geht hier um Varietäten.

Comment: @adjan: Genau. Varietäten. Keine Dialekte. Es gibt drei gleichwertige deutsche Standard-Varietäten (Varietäten, die standardisiert sind), also *Standard-Deutsch*. Deutsches Deutsch, Österreichisches Deutsch und Schweizerisches Deutsch. Die drei Varietäten unterscheiden sich in der Zahl der Sprecher, aber keine der drei ist den beiden anderen übergeordnet. Der Duden war in Österreich niemals ein offizielles Nachschlagewerk und war niemals (und ist auch jetzt nicht) eine verlässliche Quelle für österreichisches Deutsch. Dafür gibt es seit 1952 das Österreichische Wörterbuch (ÖWB).

Comment: @HubertSchölnast "all dialect and *variants*" Kannst du Englisch lesen? "Alle Dialekte und Varianten" schließt "Varietäten" nicht aus. Die deutsche Standardvarietät ist die mit Abstand häufigste; jeder der Deutsch als Fremdsprache lernt wird mit großerSicherheit "die Eins, die Zwei" und nicht "den Einser, den Zweier" kennen lernen. Das ist nur verwirrend und unnütz. Vorallem die absolut falsche Aussage "die Zwei" etc. würde man nur im Norden Deutschlands sagen. Es ist nun mal die Standardsprache, und die gilt in **ganz** Deutschland. Wenn ich Französisch lerne ist mir Quebecquois erstmal egal.

Comment: @adjan: Du siehst das aus der Sicht vom Menschen, die Deutsch als Fremdsprache lernen und entweder dort bleiben wollen wo sie jetzt sind, oder die nach Deutschland auswandern wollen. Aus deren Sicht hast du recht, für sie ist es verwirrend. Es ist aber nicht falsch und keineswegs unnütz, vor allem nicht für Menschen, die vorhaben, nach Österreich zu ziehen. In Österreich leben derzeit (Stand: 1.1.2017) laut amtlichen Quellen 181.660 Immigranten aus Deutschland, und viele von Ihnen verzweifeln in den ersten Jahren am österreichischen Deutsch (und an der Mentalität der Österreicher).

Comment: Die meisten Deutschen glauben, in Österreich spräche man dieselbe Sprache wie in Deutschland, und sind dann total überrascht davon, dass sie vieles nicht verstehen. Wenn du als Deutscher nach Italien, England, Frankreich usw. gehst, dann lernst du vorher die Sprache des Ziel-Landes. Aber offenbar glauben Deutsche, die nach Österreich kommen, sie würden die Landessprache beherrschen, und machen sich nicht die Mühe, österreichisches Deutsch zu lernen.

Comment: Als Tourist findet man es vielleicht noch amüsant, dass die Ösis so drollig reden, aber wenn man hier arbeitet und den Chef und die Kollegen nicht richtig versteht, dann empfinden das viele als gar nicht mehr lustig. Die Zuwanderer aus anderen Staaten (Türkei, Balkanstaaten) sind sich bewusst, dass sie die Landessprache lernen müssen. Den Deutschen scheint das aber mehrheitlich nicht bewusst zu sein. Viele von ihnen glauben sogar, die Österreicher ausbessern zu müssen, was gelegentlich zu Konflikten führt. Daher finde ich es wichtig, auch auf die Besonderheiten der Varietäten hervorzuheben.

Comment: *Deutsche und Österreicher werden durch die gemeinsame Sprache getrennt* (Karl Kraus). Dass Deutsche Österreicher in Österreich ausbessern war mir neu, in Deutschland **verbessern** wir sie.;)

Comment: Da hier kaum jemand sein wird, der bestreitet, dass &Pi; eine Zahl ist und es wohl "das &Pi;" heißt, wie auch *das Rho*, wohl weil alles griechische Buchstaben sind, die alle mit sächlichem Artikel gebildet werden (das Alpha, das Beta, ...), *das e* aber *die Eulersche Zahl*.

Comment: In Erklärungen für Ausländer bitte regionale Variationen entsprechend kennzeichnen! Habe ich oben gleich mal editiert. Selbe Verfahrensweise würde für Englischvariationen gelten, die nicht im Fremdsprachenunterricht vermittelt werden.

Comment: @userunknown Es ist unbewiesen und auch ausgesprochen unwahrscheinlich, das Karl Kraus das jemals gesagt hat - Die Vehemenz, mit der er auf Wiener Dialekt umgeschriebene Nestroy-Texte  abgelehnt hat und "Nestroy ist kein Wiener Dialektschriftsteller, sondern ein deutscher Satiriker" vertreten hat, spricht wohl dagegen. Wahrscheinlich handelt es sich um eine Abwandlung aus einem Zitat aus dem Englischen, das wahlweise George Bernhard Shaw oder Oscar Wilde zugesprochen wird, nach dem "England und Amerika nur durch eine gemeinsame Sprache getrennt" seien.

Comment: @userunknown nur der Vollständigkeit halber: Nach aktuellen Rechtschreibregeln heißt es entweder "die eulersche Zahl" oder die "Euler'sche Zahl".

Comment: @Tofro: Welchen Vokal vertritt der Apostroph in "Euler'sche Zahl", ein kleines I? Statt "die Eulerische Zahl"? Überzeugt mich nicht und den Schreiber des deutschen Wikipediaartikels offenbar auch nicht.

Comment: @tofro: Hier http://www.belleslettres.eu/content/zeichensetzung/apostroph.php eine recht einleuchtende Darstellung des Apostrophs.

Answer (score -1):

First the easy part:

**Letters are neuter.** Everywhere where German is spoken.

But for numbers it depends on the geographic region. In Austria (and I guess in Bavaria too), numbers are male:

> Gerhard hat **einen Sechser** gewürfelt.
>   Anna hat auf ihre letzte Matheschularbeit **einen Zweier** bekommen.
>   Mit welchem Bus bist du gefahren? - Mit **dem Vierzehner**.
>   Was hast du in deiner Geldbörse? - Ich habe **einen Zehner** und **einen Hunderter**.

Also for zero:

> Du musst **den Nuller** drücken wenn du ins Erdgeschoß fahren willst.

But in northern regions of Germany, Numbers are female:

> Gerhard hat **eine Sechs** gewürfelt.
>   Anna hat auf ihre letzte Matheschularbeit **eine Zwei** bekommen.
>   Du musst **die Null** drücken wenn du ins Erdgeschoß fahren willst.

But I do not know, if numbers of buslines or bills are male or female in northern parts of Germany (I live in Austria).

But bigger numbers are female everywhere:

> Frau Schmidt hat **eine Million** auf ihrem Konto.
>   Die Autobahn hat **eine Milliarde** gekostet.

Comment: In northern Germany both variants are used but the feminine one is much more prevalent.

Comment: Statements like "in northern regions of Germany, Numbers are female" and "In Austria (and I guess in Bavaria too), numbers are male" are slightly misleading because, as becomes clear in your examples, you are talking about two different sets of number words.

Comment: The statement that “[l]etters are neuter. Everywhere where German is spoken” is not correct. At least in Switzerland, they are often masculine (while numerals are often neuter).

Comment: At least in some dialects, letters can easily be masculine as well - My mother tended to constantly call the letters by "der" ("der A", "einen N",...)