# Was für ein Geschlecht hat eine Zahl?

Tags: gender

> **Diese Frage wurde auch hier (auf Englisch) beantwortet:**
>   *[What's the gender of digits and numbers?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/36532/9551)*

Wenn ich Zahlen im Text benutze, was für ein Geschlecht soll ich verwenden?

Z.B. als Abkürzung von "Ich möchte den Artikel 1234 kaufen" ist es "Ich möchte den 1234 kaufen"? Und statt "Mir gefällt die Option 4321" ist es "Mir gefällt die 4321"? Was passiert wenn eine Zahl alleine steht und es nicht eindeutig ist was damit gezählt wird?

Also, benutzt man kontextabhängig unterschiedliche Geschlechte, oder haben Zahlen immer ein bestimmtes Geschlecht?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Es kommt wohl darauf an, wo der Text geschrieben und verwendet werden soll. Einen ersten Hinweis hierzu gibt der Wikipedia-Artikel "[Zahlwort](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zahlwort#Substantivierung)" der erläutert, dass

- im deutschländischen Standarddeutsch Zahlwörter bei Substantivierung feminin sind
- im österreichischen Standarddeutsch hingegen ausschließlich maskulin sind.

(Die in dem Wikipedia-Artikel aufgeführte Grundlagenliteratur kann ich nicht prüfen, da sie mir nicht vorliegt.)

Das lässt sich auch aus den Diskussionen in der [verlinkten Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/36532/whats-the-gender-of-digits-and-numbers) (auf englisch) erkennen, wo in den Kommentaren ebenfalls auf die Unterschiede zwischen Deutschland und Österreich hingewiesen wird. Zusätzlich kommen dann auch noch regionale Eigenheiten und Besonderheiten hinzu, aber diese können m. E. nicht mehr dem Standarddeutsch zugerechnet werden.

Beispielsweise würde so aus

> Der Spieler fünf begeht ein Foul.

im bundesdeutschen Deutsch: "**Die Fünf** begeht ein Foul.",
hingegen im österreichischen Deutsch: "**Der Fünfer** begeht ein Foul."

Comment: Ein Beispiel mit einem männlichen Wort wäre ideal, dann könnte ich die Antwort akzeptieren. Und damit wäre es sofort erkennbar, ob es eine Rolle spielt wenn wir das Geschlecht des gezählten Wortes kennen: z.B. "Ich möchte den Artikel 1234 kaufen" - wird es "ich möchte die 1234 kaufen", oder spielt das entfernte Wort eine Rolle? Die verlinkte Englische Frage erwähnt es gar nicht.

Comment: Ja, genau, das meine ich.

Comment: Das Beispiel zur maskulinen Verwendung halte ich für fragwürdig. Fünf**er** ist immerhin ein anderes Substantiv als Fünf, wobei Fünfer freilich auch in Deutschland maskulin ist.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Die Zweifel sind verständlich. Aber aus dem Kommentar von Hubert in der verlinkten Frage geht hervor, dass das in Österreich wohl tatsächlich Standard ist.

Comment: @IQV: Das *was* Standard ist? "der Fünf"? Das bezweifle ich nicht, wenn Hubert das sagt; mein Punkt ist, dass das Beispiel das überhaupt nicht aufzeigt, weil es auf ein anderes Wort (der Fünfer) eingeht.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Ich meinte, dass das was bei der Substantivierung im deutschen Deutsch zu "die Fünf" wird im österreichischen Deutsch immer zu "der Fünfer" wird.

Comment: @IQV: Ok, aber auch in Deutschland ist mitunter "der Fünfer" gebräuchlich.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Richtig. Aber (wie man auch in der Diskussion bei der anderen Antwort sieht) ist hier die Frage, ob das eine regionale Besonderheit oder standardsprachlich ist?

Comment: @IQV: Da diese spezielle Form des Zahlsubstantivs ("Dreier" an Stelle von "Drei") hier im Südwesten sehr gebräuchlich ist, ebenso aber beispielsweise in der Formulierung "wenn ein Schüler dauerhaft nur Fünfer schreibt" des [Pinneberger Tageblatts](https://www.shz.de/lokales/pinneberger-tageblatt/ehrenrunde-status-quo-reicht-aus-id360986.html) auftaucht, bin ich zuversichtlich, dass sie zumindest deutschlandweit als mehr oder weniger gebräuchliche Form aufgefasst wird. Eventuell wäre das aber genauer durch eine separate Frage zu klären.

Answer (score 1):

Zahlen alleine sind immer weiblich. Einzige Ausnahme die mir spontan einfällt sind Geldscheine (der Zehner, der Zwanziger) die aber auch immer mit einem 'r' enden im Gegensatz zu Zahlen alleine (die Acht, die Neun, die Zehn)

Comment: Also es ist richtig "Ich möchte den Artikel 1234 kaufen", und "Ich möchte die 1234 kaufen", auch wenn es klar ist dass ich in beiden Fälle "Artikel 1234" meine?

Comment: @vsz: Ja, das ist richtig. Ein weiterer Fall, der mir einfällt, ist die Bestellung in manchen Restaurants, meistens asiatisch. Da ist es einfacher, die Nummer zu sagen, statt den langen Namen des Gerichts. Also z.B. "Ich hätte gerne die 17 und als Vorspeise die 8."

Comment: Andrer typischer Fall ist an der Tankstelle die Nennung der Tanksäule, an der man getankt hat: "Ich zahle die 3".

Comment: @tofro   ... wobei es aber auch sein könnte, dass heir "die Tanksäule" mitschwingt. Die Probe aufs Exempel müsste man mit männlichen Referenzwörtern machen. Vielleicht ein Skilift, wenn mehrere zur Auswahl stehen? "Ich nehme die 3" wäre auch dann die übliche Formulierung. Probe bestanden.

Comment: Ein Sechser ist immer männlich, egal, was er bezeichnet. (Eine Schulnote in einigen Gegenden, einen Lottogewinn, früher in einigen Gegenden ein Fünf-Pfennig-Stück.)

Comment: @CarstenS ja, aber die Sechs ist immer weiblich, so wie die Fünf oder die Vier.

Comment: Genau. Deine Aussage hat nur nichts damit zu tun, dass es um Geldscheine geht, sondern nur damit, dass es andere Zahlwörter sind.

Comment: Ein Beispiel mit einem männlichen Wort wäre ideal, dann könnte ich die Antwort akzeptieren.

Comment: Eine weitere Ausnahme sind Bus- und Straßenbahnlinien: der Fünfer, der Elfer,...

Comment: Also bei uns sagt man zB die Dreier bei der Straßenbahn, aber der Elfer beim Bus.... ich bin mir bloß nicht sicher, ob das nur so gesprochen wird, oder ob es auch grammatikalisch korrekt ist. PS @CarstenS stimmt, da hast du recht. Ist nicht nur bei Geldscheinen so.

Comment: @elPolloLoco: Stimmt. Meiner Meinung nach schwingt bei "die Dreier" das Wort Straßenbahnlinie mit, während es beim "Elfer" das Wort "Bus (der Linie 11)" ist.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: "Probe bestanden." - nicht unbedingt, da bei *durchnummerierten* Gegenständen immer auch "die Nummer" mitschwingt. Somit ist es nicht unbedingt ein Wunder, dass auch beim Silift von "der [Nummer] drei" gesprochen wird.