# Is there a way to say "double + any number" in German?

Tags: numbers

In English one can say "double seven" (any number 0-9 could be in the place of 7) and it is equivalent to 7 7. In German can someone say doppelt sieben? I have not found such instances. I have found the word "doppelt" in instances like: "doppelt so viel", "die doppelte Menge".

Is there a way to say something like "double seven" (or any number 0-9) in German (apart from saying the number twice :p)and have the meaning 7 7 ?

Thank you!

Comment: It's perhaps worth noting that "double X" is also unknown in American English.

Comment: Do you mean, for example, by dictating a phone number: "Vier, Fünf, Drei, doppel-Sieben, sechsmal die Null"?

Comment: Yes, when dictating a card number or a phone number ( i assume that the behaviour is the same): "Vier, Fünf, Drei, doppel-Sieben, sechsmal die Null".

Comment: There is also the *Schnapszahl* which is a repdigit.

Comment: I would probably say, "zweimal sieben" or something along those lines. It's hard to imagine I wouldn't be understood given the context ofcourse.

Answer (score 40):

No, that is not common practice.

You can spell out the digits "sieben-sieben" or the number "siebenundsiebzig" or can say "zweimal die Sieben" (Numbers are generally *feminine* in German).

"Doppel-..." is commonly used for letters, however: "*Bitte* schreibt man mit Doppel-t"

Comment: Thank you very very much! We can say accordingly "zweimal die drei", right? My question has to do with the article "die". It is there because the word "die Zahl" is implied, right?

Comment: @Alexia All number words are feminine, so *die drei* is correct.

Comment: @Ian thank you very much!

Comment: And it should be upper case, of course: "die Sieben". In Bavarian dialects, numbers are preferred to be masculine and with _-er_ ending: "der Siebener", "der Dreier". Because of this, "zwei Siebener" is a common way to refer to dobule seven in Austria.

Comment: @Alexia, regarding the gender, have a look at https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/36532. Btw, letters are neuter, I do not think that the gender of "Zahl" is relevant for the gender of numbers.

Comment: @tofro: You wrote: *»Numbers are generally feminine in German«* It should be *»... in German**y**«.* Because they are masculine in Austria (*»der Siebener«, »zwei Siebener«*)

Comment: @HubertSchölnast This way of expressing them also exists in Germany, but is more colloquial.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast You comment is a bit misleading. In Austria, it's "die Sieben" (this word is also used in written language in Austria), but "der Siebener" - as I already commented earlier.

Comment: board games: "Ich habe **zwei Sechsen** gewürfelt". In Austrian lottery: "Sie hatte **vier Dreier** [erraten/gewonnen]".

Comment: The last option also makes it very easy to describe even larger sequences: 777 = "dreimal die Sieben", 7777 = "viermal die Sieben", ...

Comment: @Carsten S thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 22):

It is already correct answered: It is not a common practice.

But there are exceptions:

## The zero.

There are two usages for the [Doppel-Null](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/00):

- There are double-zero agents (Doppel-Null-Agenten) in James Bond and
- the [American Roulette](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roulette#Das_amerikanische_Roulette) also contains a "Doppelnull"

This expressions are not origin German, they are calques of English expressions.

## The Six

The "[Doppel-Sechs](https://www.bravo.de/sport/was-ist-die-doppel-sechs-226401.html)" is a strategy in soccer games. See also [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittelfeldspieler#Defensiver_Mittelfeldspieler)

## Rowing

A similar expression can be found in rowing sport. Attention: This numbers have a -er at the end (*Achter* instead *Acht*).

Different [boats](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rudern#Bootsklassen) are called by the number of oars:

- [Doppelzweier](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppelzweier)
- [Doppelvierer](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppelvierer)
- Doppelachter (unusual)

See also https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skull#Skullbootsklassen

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarifications!

Comment: Note a *Null* is someone with zero competence in colloqial German, so a *Doppelnull-Agent* as used in the German dub of the James Bond movies occassionally is unwillingly funny. Of course, Sean Connery could cover that crack with ease.

Comment: @Janka haha that's a useful fun fact!

Comment: Now explain to OP what a *Doppelsechs* is ;)

Comment: Re James Bond: But note that the actual number of a »Doppel-Null-Agent« is always pronounced digit by digit. »007« is always »null null sieben«, never »doppel-null sieben«.

Comment: I'm inclined to say that terms like "Doppel-Null" exist in german because they are translations of english proper nouns - like "Double O" for Bond or "Double Zero" in roulette

Comment: Please stop saying "translation".  Calling Bond _doppel-null sieben_ is a [calque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calque).

Comment: @Malvolio I learned a new word and used it :)

Comment: @Malvolio: Please read [besc's comment](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/53630/is-there-a-way-to-say-double-any-number-in-german/53632#comment130589_53632), he is *not* called "Doppelnull Sieben" in German.

Comment: Note: Not applicable for post codes, phone and social security numbers.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper — it doesn't matter what Bond is called. "Doppelnull Sieben" is a calque.

Comment: @Malvolio: For the purpose of this answer, it arguably does, unless you wish to mislead the OP about how "Doppelnull" is used in German. Also, while I certainly appreciate having learned a new word, note that ["calque" is a synonym for "loan translation"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/calque), thus a calque is still a (specific kind of) translation.

Answer (score 7):

There **is** a way to say »double + any number« in German. Some of us pronounce a phone number (or any other) like this:

> drei, vier, sieben, Doppelfünf, acht, sechs, eins
>   (347 55 861)

This will be understood by everyone, and you won't reap any astonishment in doing this.

Comment: It's impossible for me to refute that *some people* say that. However, it seems misleading to suggest to OP that this would not cause astonishment (because it is not common practice, as you seem to agree).

Comment: Doppelfünf habe ich noch nie gehört

Comment: Could it be a regional thing, if some users have and others haven't heard of it?

Comment: Doppelsieben appears to be a brand name: https://shop.spreadshirt.de/doppelsieben/ -- surely they wouldn't choose it if people didn't understand it?

Comment: @äüö: Sieh mal [hier](https://www.boote-forum.de/showthread.php?s=c30ed5dfdf7ee0a620fa3b6c0ae2e3e9&p=17888&#post17888)

Comment: There are entries in some dictionaries: https://de.pons.com/übersetzung/deutsch-spanisch/Doppelzwei, https://beluka.de/woerterbuch/deutschtuerkisch/Doppeldrei

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Seems to be related to [Domino](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domino). Note that in this case, *Doppel-n* does not mean the sequence *nn* (or 10 *n* + *n*), but two distinct *n* (left side/right side). The same goes for *Doppelsechs* in the knut's answer.

Comment: "This will be understood by everyone, and you won't reap any astonishment in doing this." - no doubt about the first statement, but I'm not convinced of the second one.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Ein _»Doppel«_ bzw. _»doppel«_ kannst du zahlreichen Wörtern voranstellen, es sind gängige Teile des deutschen Baukastensystems, schon allein deshalb sollte es niemand verwundern.

Comment: @Pollitzer: Sicher, die "Verwunderung" hält sich, gemessen an anderen Situationen, sicherlich in Grenzen. Dennoch dürfte "fünf fünf" beim Hören meist überhaupt nicht auffallen, "Doppelfünf" schon eher.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper "'This will be understood by everyone, and you won't reap any astonishment in doing this.' - no doubt about the first statement, but I'm not convinced of the second one." I can't imagine it would be more astonishing than someone saying "double-five" in English. If you understand something it won't be all that _astonishing_. You might note how uncommon it is, but understanding is virtually the same as having already experienced, and therefore not finding particularly novel.

Comment: @JanKyuPeblik: "You might note how uncommon it is" - there you have your "astonishment".

Comment: No. There's a reason we have both those words. It is uncommon to use the word "astonishment" to refer to something that you might merely say "huh" or pause for a second over.

Answer (score 6):

In the case of games (especially games with dice) we use the term "**Pasch**" to mean double X.

e.g. "Vierer-Pasch" = 4 4

From [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasch_(Spiel)):

> Der Begriff Pasch bezeichnet bei Spielen einen Wurf mit mehreren Würfeln bei Würfel- oder Brettspielen, bei dem zwei oder mehr Würfel die gleiche Augenzahl zeigen. Man spricht dabei von einem x-er-Pasch (Dreier-Pasch, Vierer-Pasch usw.), wenn zwei oder mehr Würfel die gleiche Punktzahl zeigen.

(I am from Austria, if it matters)

Comment: Note: Not applicable for post codes, phone and social security numbers.

Comment: Die Aussage stimmt zwar, trifft aber m.E. nicht das Gefragte.

Comment: @HectorLector thanx for your answer!

Answer (score 4):

There's a perfectly clear and unambiguous way of doing this. Just say how many copies you want, and then the name of the number in plural.

- Zwei Eins**en**.
- Zwei Zwei**en**.
- Zwei Sieben**en**.

Moreover, I agree with Pollitzer that *Doppelsieben* is also clear, unambiguous and shorter.

Thus, e.g. 923333602111088084 could be pronounced

> Neun, Zwei, vier Dreien, Sechs, Null, Zwei, drei Einsen, Null, Doppelacht, Null, Acht, Vier.

However, this has the potential of confusing the listener: if the “vier Dreien” isn't spoken too slowly, the listener will parse it as “Vier, Dreien, ...»en«??” Make sure you say the “vier Dreien” quickly enough, almost as it were a single word, so the listener doesn't parse it as a separate “Vier”.

In practice I think I'd actually say *viermal die Drei* to avoid this misunderstanding. So it would rather sound

> Neun, Zwei, viermaldieDrei, Sechs, Null, Zwei, dreimaldieEins, Null, Doppelacht, Null, Acht, Vier.

Answer (score 0):

At least in the game of backgammon, it is common: played with 2 dices, you often say "Ich habe doppel-fünf" or similar instead of "Ich habe einen Fünferpasch". But I have not heard it with *any* other game or situation ever.

Comment: I thought of backgammon as well. We have to consider that there is probably a great deal of English influence in the backgammon terminology because the British players shaped the game in its renaissance during the 20th century.